# NodeJS: Most efficient way to use "require"

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to use NodeJS's `require` function?  By this, I'm referring to the placement of the `require` statement.  Isf it better to load all dependencies from the beginning of the script, as you need them, or does it not make a notable difference whatsoever?

[This article](http://thenodeway.io/posts/how-require-actually-works/?utm_source=fredkschott.com&utm_medium=referral) has a lot useful information regarding how `require` works, though I still can't come to a definitive conclusion as to which method would be most efficient.

Comment: Put it at the top and forget about it. You should only call require once, otherwise you're just pulling a cached object and creating more work than you need to. This is a silly question. How you use require isn't usually going to have any significant impact on performance, unless you do something as silly as calling `require` in a function that gets called often, or in a loop(super silly). Just keep doing what you're doing, there is no super magical optimization to be found here.

Comment: @tsturzl: I've had non-trivial performance issues from `require()`ing too much synchronously (an async request from an earlier file timed out, IIRC)

Comment: @SLaks it could be that you are doing one of the "silly things" I described. Calling `require` has some overhead, and should be done only on start up, and avoided as much as possible during run time.

Comment: @tsturzl: `require()`ing an already-loaded file has zero overhead.

Comment: @SLaks Not at all. The module cache is more complicated than that especially if you're loading from a different directory. For example `var a = require('./myModule')` and `var b = require('../myModule')`, `a` and `b` are not the same instance.

Comment: at the top.

_(unless you're doing something fancy like dynamic loading of modules depending on run time conditions etc - in which case you wouldn't be asking this)_

Comment: @SLaks And passing by reference isn't zero overhead still, but its not significant. You still create a reference if you require a cached module.

Comment: @tsturzl: No.  `require()` fully resolves paths before caching, so different directories will still use the same instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using node.js for some sort of server environment, several things are generally true about that server environment:

1. You want **fast response time** to any given request.
2. The code that runs for processing requests **should not use synchronous I/O** operations because that seriously lessens the scalability of the server.
3. Server startup time is generally **not something you need to optimize for** (within reason) so if you're going to pay an initialization cost somewhere, it is usually better paid once at server startup time.

So, given that `require()` uses synchronous I/O when the module has not yet been cached, that means you really don't generally want to be doing `require()` operations inside a request handler.  And, you want fast response times for your request handlers so you don't want `require()` calls inside your handler anyway.

All of these leads to a general rule of thumb that **you load necessary modules at startup time** into a module level variable that you can reuse from one request to the next and you don't load modules inside your request handlers.

---

In addition to all of this, if you put all your `require()` statements in a block near the top of your module, it makes your module a lot more self-documenting about what other modules it depends on and how it initializes those modules.  If `require()` statements are sprinkled all over the code, then it makes it a lot harder for a developer to see what this module is using without a lot more study of the code.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what performance characteristics you're looking for.

`require()` is not cheap; it has to read the JS file from disk, parse it, and execute any top-level code (and do all of that recursively for all files `require()`d by that file).

If you put all of your `require()`s on top, your code may take more time to start, but it won't suddenly slow down later.  (note that moving the `require()` further down in the synchronous top-level code will make no difference beyond order of execution).

If you only `require()` other modules when first used asynchronously, your first request may be noticeably slower, as Node parses all of your dependencies.  This also means that any errors from dependencies won't be caught until later.  (note that all `require()` calls are cached, so the second request won't do any more work)

---

The other disadvantage to scattering `require()` calls throughout your code is that it makes it less readable; it's very nice to easily see exactly what each file depends on up top.

Comment: This is a really over simplified view of commonJS. Require caches JS from disk, so it only has the overhead on first call, otherwise it caches the `module.exports` object in memory. It's worth noting this overhead is only typically seen on the first require as long as the same path is called to require that module.

Comment: @tsturzl: Yes; I already wrote that.  And `require()` fully resolves its paths, so you don't need to worry about duplicates (unless you have two copies of the module on disk)

Comment: this is not true and is depicted directly in the node.js core module documents as seen [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats)

Comment: @tsturzl: That's only if there are multiple copies on disk. You can see this in the source: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L143

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you should be aware that...

- making sure that you call all `require()` at the start of your process gives you instant feedback wether all modules can be parsed and initialized. Your process would "fail early" and not depending on it's usage, which is good
- OTOH if your program is not a server-like long-running process (and rather a complex command line utility), it could be inefficient to load many modules that are not being used at all.

Basically you should be aware about the `require()` effects and decide the best strategy based on the kind of program you are developing. That said, it's usually the best to load "all" modules at startup.